# How can I modify ISO files on mac OS?

Tags: macos

I downloaded Windows 8.1 ISO File from Microsoft website but I need to modify if (add a file to it), it seems like I am unable to do that on mac even though it's possible to do on Windows, any idea how can I accomplish this?a

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029). Why do you want to add a file?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is to modify the bootable ISO and create a new ISO that's still bootable.

The steps below are based on the article
[Modify a bootable .iso image (macOS)](https://epir.at/2013/03/10/modify-a-bootable-.iso-image-macos/).

- Download and install the `geteltorito` Perl script:

  ```
    curl -O https://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/~krienke/ftp/noarch/geteltorito/geteltorito/geteltorito
    chmod +x ./geteltorito
  ```
- Save El Torito boot information:

  ```
    geteltorito -o boot.bin /path/to/image.iso
  ```
- Copy and modify the data:

  ```
    mkdir ~/image_folder
    cp /Volumes/Mounted_image ~/image_folder
    cp /path/to/boot.bin ~/image_folder
  ```
- Reassemble bootable ISO into `new_image.iso`:

  ```
    mkisofs -udf -no-emul-boot -relaxed-filenames -joliet-long -hide boot.bin -b boot.bin -D -o ./new_image.iso ~/image_folder
  ```